# TextSwitcher flicker/stutter sometimes

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-animation, textswitcher

I'm using a `TextSwitcher` to automatically switch text when certain `broadcasts` are received, and I add slide in / out animation for this TextSwitcher. But sometimes (like 30% of time) when the `TextSwitcher` switches from the textView before last one to the last one, there's  a flicker happens.

Visually what I see is that `State4` slided out, `State5` slided in, when `State5` was not sliding in completely, `State4` came back again and slided out, then `State5` slided in. I've checked the logs and print every broadcast, they're received in correct order. Seems to me it's the UI that acts weird.

Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks!!!

Some codes:

```
<TextSwitcher
android:id="@+id/ts1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

And I use `setFactory` to set `TextView` of the `TextSwitcher`.

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) textSwitcher.getCurrentView();
switch (state) {
    case state1:
        text = state1;
        break;
    case state2:
        text = state2;
        break;
    case state3:
        text = state3;
        break;
    case state4:
        text = state4;
        break;
    case state5:
        text = state5;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
if (!textView.getText().toString().equals(text))
    textSwitcher.setText(text);
```

The text will switch from 1 to 5 by order, and 5 is ending state. Not sure why sometimes 5 will flicker back to 4 and then to 5 again. I also checked if current text in `textSwitcher` is the same with next one, we don't do `setText()` so that no animation will be performed.

```
private void setFactoryForTextSwitcher(final TextSwitcher textSwitcher) {
    textSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        public TextView makeView() {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setSingleLine(true);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return textView;
        }
    });
}


private void loadAnimationForTextSwitcher() {
    final Animation slideInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.animator.slide_in);
    final Animation slideOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.animator.slide_out);
    textSwitcher.setInAnimation(slideInAnimation);
    textSwitcher.setOutAnimation(slideOutAnimation);
}
```

These 2 methods are called during initialization.

Comment: You might need to show the java code to illustrate the problem better.

Comment: @Elye Updated! Thanks.

Comment: where is your setFactory code and in/out animation code?

Comment: @Elye updated those methods.

Comment: The layout seems incorrect. Why do you have TextViews wrapped by TextSwitcher? We only need TextSwitcher

Comment: You don't need to clearAnimation, and seInAnimation and setOutAnimation twice.

Comment: @Elye Sorry I pasted my older version of code. I'm updating now. I only have TextSwitcher in xml, and only setAnimation once. The flicker seems to me is more like a random thing, like 30-40% of time i can see it.

Comment: What cause the change of state? Is it automatically, or manually?

Comment: @Elye It's automatically, that's why I have a check here `if (!textView.getText().toString().equals(text))`, I don't want it to setText() twice.

Comment: In this case, perhaps you could share the code of how this is done automatically, as the time and delay sequence could have impact on the animation.